# Auto reopen/refresh document

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, excel, word, refresh

Is it possible to automatically reopen office document i.e excel sheet or word document from SharePoint?

The documents are read only and I want a solution to refresh the document automatically when read by people. Is there any mechanism that can do this?

Please suggest.

Comment: question is confusing .. try to make it clear more

Comment: I wrote it in different way.

Comment: You mean to say if someone having rights has updated the documents in SharePoint, then on other hand users who are just readers and have synced these documents on desktop from SharePoint, should be able to see the latest updates. And this refreshment of document should be automatically. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Open excel document on some computer and then edit document on server. Opened document will still showing old version. You have to reload it manually from sharepoint.